# How to create a folder using mkdir in Perl?

Tags: perl, directory, mkdir

I want to create a folder in a particular path using `mkdir`.

Comment: "_... where my perl script doesnot present using mkdir._" -- what does that mean?

Comment: For example, The perl script is present in D:/Scripts folder and I want to create new folders using "mkdir" command in D:/Test/Data path.

Comment: Why not use `system('mkdir','d:\test\data');`?

Comment: NOTE: perl's `mkdir` does not create directories recursively, please see documentation for [mkdir](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/mkdir.html) where you will find reference to **make_path**.

Comment: Re "*Why not use `system('mkdir','d:\test\data');`?*", Because most people see the value in avoiding launching a shell when a simple system call can be made.

Comment: @PolarBear  I would advise against the use of external commands when there's a solid Perl utility like `File::Path::make_path` (which you also mention in your good second comment).  And given that the module is in core I see strictly no reason to resort to a much more complicated process of going out to the system (the reason for "why not").

Comment: @ikegami -- then why not use recursively [mkdir](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/mkdir.html)? Split path into array, check from first element of array if the directory not exists then create it, and continue until last element in array. Simple and not external modules require at all.

Comment: Re "*then why not use recursively mkdir?*", You mean instead of `make_path`? The number of benefits of writing one line of well-tested and maintained code over 50 new lines of code should be obvious

Comment: @ikegami - OP's question was **I want to create a folder in a particular path using mkdir** - is it? Why go to extent of _perl_ one liner when directory can be created in shell with _mkdir_? It looks like you missed the point OP was trying to convey.

Comment: @PolarBear Noone suggested using a Perl one-liner to create a dir from the shell. That would indeed be a bad idea. ...Except when it isn't. IIRC, `cmd`'s doesn't have an equivalent to unix's `mkdir -p`, so using Perl's  `make_path` would be an useful then.

Comment: @ikegami -- Really? In _Windows 10_ command `help mkdir` gives following sentence _MKDIR creates any intermediate directories in the path, if needed._ with an example `mkdir \a\b\c\d`!

Comment: I did say "if I remember correctly", so can the attitude. I was at a restaurant at the time, and `mkdir` [hasn't always behaved that way](http://web.csulb.edu/~murdock/mkdir.html). So yeah, ignore the second half of my last comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `D:/Test/Data` exists

```
my $dir_qfn = 'D:/Test/Data/foo';
mkdir($dir_qfn)
   or $!{EEXIST}   # Don't die if $dir_qfn exists.
   or die("Can't create directory \"$dir_qfn\": $!\n");
```

If if might not,

```
use File::Path qw( make_path );

my $dir_qfn = 'D:/Test/Data/foo';
make_path($dir_qfn);
```

Comment: Thanks for the support. The below code is working                                                        my $dir_qfn = "D:\\Test\\Data\\";
 mkdir $dir_qfn.sample_.$i;

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
my $dir = "../../folder/my_dir";
# if dir not exists create it
unless (-d "$dir") {`mkdirhier $dir`;}
```

Comment: There are so many issues with this, I can't list them all in a single comment.

Answer (score -1):

this syntax will check for directory existence and create it if needed

```
# here include path to new directory name
$newdir = './directory_name';
opendir(DIR, $newdir) || mkdir($newdir,0777) || die "Cannot create directory $newdir; $!";
```

Comment: Re "*check for directory existence*", There's no reason to do that. It's slower, and it introduces a race condition. See the earlier answer.